# Multiple languages and keyboard layout web support

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, web

I have Web Page and global search in it, I want to make the text-box of the global search to be able to search by languages and by keyboard layout.

lets say I'm typing the letter D I want to find the result with the letter D and with the keyboard layout of the specific country ( In case the user was on English but intend to write in its local language)
the layout is can be hard coded prefer no too.

Comment: There are multiple keyboard layouts for English, so I doubt you can infer that from the key pressed

Comment: ok so lets say I will hardcoded all the pairs in the layout that I need,
what is the best practice to search by content, you know in case the user typed D and this is what he meant .
and search toby keyboard layout ( the pairs of the layout known in advanced)

Comment: Not everybody is using qwerty https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvorak_keyboard_layout

Comment: I would just use fuzzy search library e.g. [fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/)

Comment: Thanks, Didn't think about the qwerty and etc, you are very right.
But specific to my question its inner website for my company and we have standart for out devices. but thanks a lot